# Convert an excel range into an image using python

Tags: python, excel, linux, automation

I'm trying to convert a range in an excel file into an image. I tried using the xlwings method but it didn't work because my os is Linux and Linux does not support that package. I also tried the excel2image method but it also didn't work. I even tried converting the datafame to an html file (instead of an excel file) then convert that to an image but both packages I used (html2image & imgkit) are not supported on Linux. Does anyone know a method that will work on Linux? I know that you can convert dataframes to images but the styling options for dataframes are very limited.

here is the code I used

1st method using xlwings

```
wb = xw.Book(file_path)
sheet = wb.sheets[0]
img_range = "B2:F26"

xw.Range(img_range).api.copy_picture()
sheet.api.paste()
pic = sheet.pictures[0]

img = ImageGrab.grabclipboard()
img_name = image_1
img.save(img_name + ".png")
pic.delete()

wb.close()
```

I got this error: xlwings.XlwingsError: Your platform only supports the instantiation via xw.Book(json=...).
By the way, this worked perfectly when I tried it on a mac !

I even tried to add: app = xw.app() but I got the following error:
app = xw.app() AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'apps'

2nd method using excel2img

```
import excel2img
excel2img.export_img(file_path, img_name, "B2:F26")
```

This one didn't work because this package works only with windows

Comment: Add the code with your attempts.

Comment: How does a *"range"* look exactly please?

Comment: @DigitalFarmer I added the code I tried.

Comment: @MarkSetchell this is what I mean by range: "B2:F26"

Comment: Does that make a 5x25 image? What sort of numbers are in the cells?

Comment: @MarkSetchell the type of data in the cells doesn't matter, it could be a table with dates and numbers or names. The script above converts that range to an image but it doesn't work on linux. When I tried it on a mac, it worked and I got the images.

Comment: @MarkSetchell I think the word "convert" was confusing here. What I meant is basically, take a screenshot of a range and save it as an image. In this case I can't use pyscreenshot because it saves my "active" screen and doesn't open the excel file to take a screenshot of the range.

Comment: Html2Image should work on Windows, MacOS *and* Linux. You have to install Chrome/Chromium and the module should automatically detect them. If not, you can always specify the path to your browser executable using the `browser_executable` parameter/attribute.